# no sign change found in 1000 iterations in R

Tags: r, root

my question is "Find the maximum of the function myfun = - (sin(x)-3)^2 + 1 ,on the interval (0,5), and please answer x=? and f(x)= ?"

there is my code in R：

```
f <- function(x) { return((-1*sin(x)-3)^2+1 }
result <- uniroot(f,c(0,5),extendInt = "yes"
result$root
result$f.root
```

but the console is ：

> Error in uniroot(f, c(0, 5), extendInt = "yes") : 
>     no sign change found in 1000 iterations

what's wrong with my code 
Thanks a lot

Comment: `uniroot` doesn't find a maximum, it finds a zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`optimize` is the standard function for finding a max or min of a 1-dimensional function. `uniroot` is used for finding a root (0) of the function, not max or min values.

```
optimize(f, interval = c(0, 5), maximum = TRUE)
$maximum
[1] 1.570796

$objective
[1] 17
```

See `?optimize` for examples and details.

(Note: I added a `)` to the `f` in your question to avoid syntax errors.)

Answer (score 1):

The base R function being used in the question is wrong. From the documentation:

**uniroot**

> The function `uniroot` searches the interval from lower to upper for a
>   root (i.e., zero) of the function f with respect to its first
>   argument.

**optimize**

> The function `optimize` searches the interval from lower to upper for
>   a minimum or maximum of the function f with respect to its first
>   argument.

**Code**

```
f <- function(x) { (-1*sin(x) - 3)^2 + 1 }
m <- optimize(f, c(0, 5), maximum = TRUE)
m
#$maximum
#[1] 1.570796
#
#$objective
#[1] 17


curve(f, 0, 5)
points(m$maximum, m$objective, pch = 16, col = "red")
```

[image]

Also, the function `f` is identical to

```
g <- function(x) { (sin(x) + 3)^2 + 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For you purpose, you should use `optim()` or `optimize()`, instead of `uniroot()`, i.e.:

Given `f <- function(x) -(sin(x)-3)^2+1` (***the objective function in you code is not the one as you described at the beginning of your post***), you will get the result via

```
optim(0,f,method = "L-BFGS-B",lower = 0,upper = 5,control = list(fnscale = -1))

> optim(0,f,method = "L-BFGS-B",lower = 0,upper = 5,control = list(fnscale = -1))
$par
[1] 1.570796

$value
[1] -3

$counts
function gradient 
       7        7 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

or

```
optimize(f, interval = c(0, 5), maximum = TRUE)

> optimize(f, interval = c(0, 5), maximum = TRUE)
$maximum
[1] 1.570796

$objective
[1] -3
```